# Symbol for functions that vanish on boundary?

Tags: analysis, soft-question, notation

If I have a domain $ M \subset \mathbb{R}^n $, is there a standard symbol for the set of functions $ f \in C^\infty(M) $ that vanish on $ \partial M$ ? I feel like I have seen this before, but I'm just forgetting where.

Comment: Don't know if this is what you are searching for but in $\mathbb{R}^n$ we use the notion $C_0$ for continuous functions which vanish as $\|x\|\to \infty$. If you are $C^\infty$ anyway you could say functions with support $M$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_%28mathematics%29

Comment: So Do you mean smooth functions with compact support? To my best understanding, there's no standard one. But I've often seen $C_0^\infty(M)$.